# push_back(this) pushes wrong pointer onto vector

Tags: c++

I have a vector of UnderlyingClass pointers stored in another object, and inside a method in UnderlyingClass I want to add the "this" pointer to the end of that vector.  When I look at the contents of the vector immediately after the push_back call, the wrong pointer is in there.  What could be going wrong?

```
cout << "this: " << this << endl;
aTextBox.callbacks.push_back(this); 
cout << "size is " << aTextBox.callbacks.size() << endl;
cout << "size-1: " << aTextBox.callbacks[aTextBox.callbacks.size()-1] << endl;
cout << "back: " << aTextBox.callbacks.back() << endl;
cout << "0: " << aTextBox.callbacks[0] << endl;
cout << "this: " << this << endl;
cout << "text box ptr: " << &aTextBox << endl;
cout << "text box callbacks ptr: " << &(aTextBox.callbacks) << endl;
```

Here's the output:

```
this: 0x11038f70
size is 1
size-1: 0x11038fa8
back: 0x11038fa8
0: 0x11038fa8
this: 0x11038f70
text box ptr: 0x11039070
text box callbacks ptr: 0x11039098
```

By the way, callbacks is a vector of WebCallback pointers, and UnderlyingClass implements WebCallback:

```
std::vector<WebCallback*> callbacks;


class UnderlyingClass
    :public WebCallback
```

Copied from comments: (see Answer below)

output:

```
this: 0x6359f70 
size is 1 
size-1: 0x6359fa8 
back: 0x6359fa8 
0: 0x6359fa8 
this: 0x6359f70 
WebCallback This: 0x6359fa8 
text box ptr: 0x635a070 
text box callbacks ptr: 0x635a098
```

okay, so that explains why the pointers don't match up.

My real question, then, is this:

how do I get the correct version of a method to be called? Specifically, WebCallback stipulates that a function onWebCommand() be implemented, and right now callbacks[0]->onWebCommand() is not causing the onWebCommand() that I wrote in UnderlyingClass to be executed.

Comment: This surely sounds like multiple inheritance.

Comment: Does UnderlyingClass have any other base classes?

Comment: Dagnammit. That's the second time today litb has beaten me by exactly 47 seconds. I'm like a quarter light second closer to the USA than him, I should be winning these!

Comment: Fool, you cannot out-type litb, give up!

Comment: Actually, it's not as much as a whole quarter light second, either.

Comment: yes, it has one other base class.  So depending on which base class it thinks it is, it gets a different pointer?

Comment: A pointer has to point to a type that is compatible with that type. If you inherit from multiple types, the compiler has to ensure that pointers to inherited types are compatible, which usually means it "embeds" the base classes in the derived class.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This can happen with multiple inheritance, if your layout looks like this:

```
class UnderlyingBase {
  char d[56];
};

class UnderlyingClass
    :public UnderlyingBase, 
     public WebCallback {

};
```

Then the layout can be like this, for each object involved. The last one is the complete object containing the first two ones as base-class sub-objects, and that you take the pointer of, and which will be converted to `WebCallback*`.

```
[UnderlyingBase]
 > char[56]: 56 bytes, offset 0x0

[WebCallback]
 > unknown:  x bytes, offset 0x0

[UnderlyingClass]
 > [UnderlyingBase]: 56 bytes (0x38 hex), offset 0x0
 > [WebCallback]:    x  bytes, offset 0x38
```

Now since your vector contains `WebCallback*`, the compiler adjusts the pointer to point to the `WebCallback` sub-object, while when it would point to `UnderlyingClass` or `UnderlyingBase`, it would start 0x38 (56) bytes earlier.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense.

So, this question arose from me attempting to debug another issue; is multiple inheritance at work on the larger issue?

Specifically, WebCallback has a virtual method onWebCommand(), which of course is implemented in UnderlyingClass, and at another part in the code I call onWebCommand() on each of the members of callbacks.  Right now, that code for UnderlyingClass::onWebCommand() is not being executed; what's wrong?

Comment: That should work. check whether both methods really have the same signature (including const-ness).

Comment: indeed, there was a problem with the signature.  Thanks for the help - great explanation.

Answer (score 3):

Add this to your print out:

```
cout << "this: " << this << endl;
cout << "WebCallback This: " << dynamic_cast<WebCallback*>(this) << endl;
```

I bet this is what you are looking for.

Comment: output:
this: 0x6359f70
size is 1
size-1: 0x6359fa8
back: 0x6359fa8
0: 0x6359fa8
this: 0x6359f70
WebCallback This: 0x6359fa8
text box ptr: 0x635a070
text box callbacks ptr: 0x635a098

okay, so that explains why the pointers don't match up.  My real question, then, is this:

how do I get the correct version of a method to be called?  Specifically, WebCallback stipulates that a function onWebCommand() be implemented, and right now callbacks[0]->onWebCommand() is not causing the onWebCommand() that I wrote in UnderlyingClass to be executed.

Comment: Add to your question the definition of WebCallback AND UnderlyingClass. I bet your definition of the virutal method is not correct.

Comment: d'oh, method had the wrong signature (constness) and an assert(false) I put in the interface's version of the method wasn't getting hit because asserts weren't enabled in my gdb session.  Thanks for the help!